# XSL FO - Formatting tables for overflow

Tags: apache, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have an XSL-FO table that works almost perfectly.  Unfortunately, I am finding that when I have many items (enough to wrap to page 2), the table gets too close to the footer.  I want there to be some padding between the table and the footer.

I tried adding `padding-after`, but instead of padding I get overflow errors from Apache FOP.

> Apr 7, 2011 1:29:41 PM
>   org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener
>   processEvent WARNING: Content
>   overflows the viewport of the
>   fo:region-after on page 1 in bloc
>   k-progression direction by 25966
>   millipoints. (See position 68:53)

How can I do it?

```
<fo:block overflow="clip" padding-after="1em">
        <!-- table start -->
        <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" border-collapse="separate" >
```

Comment: Not about XSLT stylesheet but XSL-FO vocabulary. Retagging.

Comment: Is overflow="clip" a valid attribute value? I cannot find it here: http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#overflow

Comment: @RobertG - Looks like you are correct.  I don't know where I came up with this value as I wrote it 2 years ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 <!--Footer-->
    <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
      <fo:block font-size="12pt" padding-before="1em"
```

I padded the footer instead of the table.  For whatever reason, it respects the footer padding.